# How to know last row when iterating cursor on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

How to know last row when iterating cursor on SQL Server?

I have tried with counter and `@@CURSOR_ROWS` and `@@FETCH_STATUS`, but it doesn't work well or I didn't use them in proper way.

EDIT:

Well, yeah, composing string with comma... `,` on the end of each loop. Of course, before return I can cut off the last character which will be `,` but I'm wondering is this only way?

However, there is a lot of situations, it may be good to know how to recognise the last row.

Comment: What will you use this information for? Is it possible to transform your problem such that you do something special for the *first* row rather than the last? (classic example - adding commas between elements. Change the logic to prepending commas to all but the first row rather than trying to append commas to all but the last row)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever please see the edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, putting commas between elements is far more easily realised by doing something special for the *first* row, rather than the last.<sup>1,2</sup>

Rather than

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    SET @value = @value + @newelement + ','

    ...
END
```

And trying to work out how to treat the last row specially, it's far easier to do:

```
SET @first = 1
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    IF @first = 1
        SET @first = 0
    ELSE
        SET @value = @value + ','

    SET @value = @value + @newelement

    ...
END
```

---

An alternative transformation, if you *really* do need to do something for the last row is to use intermediate variables and a non-standard cursor loop:

```
declare boris cursor for select top 10 name from sys.objects order by name

declare @name sysname
declare @nametemp sysname

open boris
fetch next from boris into @nametemp
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    set @name = @nametemp --Use SELECT if multiple variables to be assigned

    fetch next from boris into @nametemp

    if @@FETCH_STATUS!=0
    begin
        print 'and finally'
    end

    print @name
END

close boris
deallocate boris
```

Which prints (for me, in a nearly empty DB):

```
EventNotificationErrorsQueue
filestream_tombstone_2073058421
filetable_updates_2105058535
IsIt
QueryNotificationErrorsQueue
queue_messages_1977058079
queue_messages_2009058193
queue_messages_2041058307
ServiceBrokerQueue
and finally
sysallocunits
```

But I'd strongly recommend the first type of transformation instead.

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't just a T-SQL thing either. In most programming languages, it's usually far easier if you can transform your problem from "treat the last iteration differently" into "treat the first iteration differently"

<sup>2</sup>And, of course, insert usual warnings about cursors being a last resort in SQL, use set-based approaches unless or until they're proved to be inadequate.

Comment: no doubt you are right, I'll do as you propose but what if I need to execute storproc before the last row for some reason?

Comment: @dllhell - I've given an alternative, but I'd recommend against it, if you possibly can find a transformation of the first type.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the condition after the FETCH:

```
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(max) = '(';
DECLARE @column_name nvarchar(255);
DECLARE colums CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TOP 10 name FROM sys.all_columns 
OPEN colums
FETCH NEXT FROM colums INTO @column_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement 
                      + QUOTENAME(@column_name)                   
    FETCH NEXT FROM colums INTO @column_name
    SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement + CASE WHEN @@FETCH_STATUS != -1 THEN ',' ELSE ')' END 
                      + char(13)
END
CLOSE colums
DEALLOCATE colums
print @sqlStatement
```